# Inequivalence of templated types using aliased template names

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, using

My goal is to record the name of a templated type when defining other types with template template parameters. The problem I have encountered is that the resulting types are considered to be inequivalent.

To achieve this I have tried using a templated "using" alias to record the name given as the template template argument. I then refer to the alias to recover the name. An example of where this is useful is when I have a templated function that returns a type with template template parameter that needs to be deduced.

The following code shows my approach:

```
include <type_traits>

template<typename X>
struct TT {};

template<template<typename> class T>
struct UU {
  template<typename X>
  using name = T<X>;
};

template<template<typename> class T>
struct VV {};

int main() {
  static_assert(std::is_same<
    TT<int>,
    UU<TT>::template name<int>
  >::value, "Templated type instances are distinct");
  static_assert(std::is_same<
    VV<TT>,
    VV<UU<TT>::template name>
  >::value, "Template type instances using template names are distinct");

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling as follows:

```
c++ -std=c++14 Test.cpp -o Test
```

Yields:

```
Test.cpp:20:3: error: static_assert failed "Template type instances using template names are distinct"
```

Is there another way of recording and using template names?

Can someone direct me to the part of the standard where this behavior is specified?

Comment: There's an active core issue about this.

Comment: http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1286 cc @T.C.

Comment: gcc 5.3 does not have a problem with the alias.

Comment: Your example works with gcc 4.9

Comment: @Jarod42 - fine, I'll include the hobbit.

Comment: @sam-varshavchik (& dtbeaver) I tested with gcc 4.8.4 and clang 7.0.2 - it is very good to know that an upgrade (at least for gcc) will resolve this.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you for the link to the issue.

Comment: I think this is more or less the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19314277/2796908